# Generalized associated Legendre Polynomials

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, expansion

Is there a simple way to calculate the *generalized* associated Legendre polynomials in Python ([article](https://academic.oup.com/gji/article/34/4/451/663524?login=true))?
[image: Generalized Associated Legendre Polynomials]

I know that you can get the associated Legendre Polynomials using SciPy or pyshtools ([article](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.lpmv.html)), but not the generalized ones (having two raised indices).

Comment: I haven't seen any full implementation of these polynomials. However, the paper you reference, and references therein, provide a number of recurrence relations that could be used as a basis to a numerical evaluation using [continued fraction expansions](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-1-4020-6948-2). Another way would be relate the function to an hypergeometic series, and use existing packages to compute it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to implement the derivative is to use the grad-functionality of jax: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html

Good luck :)